# How to write a generic recursive makefile

Tags: recursion, makefile

I whould like to write a generic make file.

For example, given a such tree :

```
/
|-Makefile
|-Foo
|  |-Makefile
|  |-Foo1
|  |  |-Makefile
|  |  |-Foo11
|  |-Foo2
|  |-Makefile
|-Bar
|  |-Makefile
|  |-Bar1
|  |  |-Makefile
|  |  |-Bar11
|  |  |  |-Makefile
|  |-Bar2
|  |  |-Makefile
|
```

I want by calling `make <target>` on the root makefile, it calls automatically `make <target>` on all sub-dir makefiles

How to do a such thing ?

(note : the list of the dirs can be in a variable)

Comment: Do the intermediate directory makefiles have any work they need to do themselves or is that job relegated only to the leaf directories?

Comment: all leaf should be independent, the goal is to "forward" the targets to build : if I all `make something` on top dir, it call recursively `make something` on child dirs

Comment: The question is which makefiles have a `something` target that does work (and doesn't just recurse). Is that only the bottom ones or can it be any (and if it isn't a leaf does it also need to recurse)?

Comment: any, and it also needs to recurse

Answer (score 0):

I've eventually found that "commandline target arguments" is called "Goal" in make language...

then, It has been quite easy to answer my question :

```
# get subdirs ($$ to escape the $ character)
# REC = $(shell find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed -e '/^\.$$/ d' -e 's|\./||')
# As corrected by  Etan Reisner (Thank you !) :
REC = $(shell find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '%P\n' -type d)

.PHONY: rec $(REC)

rec: $(REC)

$(REC):
    $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) -C $@

# for implicit rules
%: rec

# for goals
$(MAKECMDGOALS) : rec
```

then, any target is forwarded to the leaf, even if the target doesn't exist in this Makefile, it will be executed in any makefile that contains it

Comment: Use `-mindepth 1` to have find not return `.` and `-printf '%P\n'` to have it not print the leading `./`.